# Unexplained "no such file or directory" in compiled code

Tags: g++

The following copied and modified code reads the space bar to activate data capture from attached test equipment.  Without the intervening code summarized below, it runs fine.  I have avoided "using namespace std" by creating a kbrd namespace and using only the standard commands I need. The code compiles without difficulty, but when I run it with the necessary code to capture keyboard data and initialize the test gear, it runs to "Check point Alpha" and waits.  When I hit space bar (or any other key!), it prints:

> ```
> Check Point Beta
> No such file or directory.
> ```

Very similar code using the left mouse button to collect data runs as expected.  I am constructing a small computer, using a "paper" display for portable use outdoors, and would like to have code that does not need a mouse...

I have run out of things to try to fix this.  Your help is requested and will be much appreciated.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <linux/input.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <float.h>
    #include <sa_api.h>
    #pragma comment(lib,"sa_api.lib")
    #undef max
    #undef min

   namespace kbrd{   
     const char *dev = "/dev/input/event3";
     struct input_event ev;
     ssize_t n;
     int fd;}

   using std::cin;
   using std::cout;
   using std::__cxx11::string;
   using std::endl;
   using std::ofstream;
   using std::ios;

   int main(void)
   {
    [[Code which 
      Initiates equipment API, prompts screen & reads keyboard to 
      gather details to be stored with data from attached test 
      equipment...]]`

    while (N_az <Num_Samples) {

      kbrd::fd = open(kbrd::dev, O_RDONLY);
      if (kbrd::fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s.\n", kbrd::dev, 
        strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
      }
      //and then read keyboard events from the device:
      cout << "Check Point Alpha" << endl;
      while (1) {
        kbrd::n = read(kbrd::fd, &kbrd::ev, sizeof kbrd::ev);
        if (kbrd::n == (ssize_t)-1) {
          if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
          else
            break;
        } else
        if (kbrd::n != sizeof kbrd::ev) {
          errno = EIO;
          break;
        }
        cout << "Check Point Beta" << endl;

        if (kbrd::ev.type == EV_KEY && kbrd::ev.value == 0 /*&& 
            kbrd::ev.value <= 2 */&& kbrd::ev.code == 57){
          cout << "Check Point Charlie" << endl;            

          continue;

          [[ Code to read attached test gear & store data, one point at a 
             time...]]

          N_az = N_az + 1;
        }
        else {
          fflush(stdout);
          fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(errno));
          return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
      }
    } 

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I hit space bar (or any other key!), it prints:
>
> ```
> Check Point Beta
> No such file or directory.
> ```

because your code is

> ```
>    cout << "Check Point Beta" << endl;
>
>    if (kbrd::ev.type == EV_KEY && kbrd::ev.value == 0 /*&& 
>        kbrd::ev.value <= 2 */&& kbrd::ev.code == 57){
>      cout << "Check Point Charlie" << endl;            
>      ...
>    }
>    else {
>      fflush(stdout);
>      fprintf(stderr, "%s.\n", strerror(errno));
>      return EXIT_FAILURE;
>    }
> ```

that means `(kbrd::ev.type == EV_KEY && kbrd::ev.value == 0 /*&& kbrd::ev.value <= 2 */&& kbrd::ev.code == 57)` is false, *No such file or directory* is coming from *strerror* so you have an error somewhere before and probably not in the *read*, reset *errno* to 0 before the *read*. Warning when there is no error *errno* is *not* reset to 0, it is only set in case of an error, so it is your responsibility to reset it to 0.

Just temporarily write the values of *kbrd::ev.type / kbrd::ev.value / kbrd::ev.code* before the test and run your program to know what are the values when you press the space bar allowing you to modify your code in consequence

Comment: thank you, bruno, for your instruction.  Will post further results after following...

Comment: @LawrenceRagan so, what is the result ?

Comment: So, I dug into the problem in considerable detail, and concluded that using the keyboard destroyed the structure in some manner that I never understood.  So I decided to use a simpler approach.  The only key that dumps the buffer is the "return" key, so I wrote a simple routine to use the return key.  I included a test for escape-return sequence to exit midway through the data set.  There is probably a more eloquent code to accomplish the same thing, but this one works for me.

Comment: @LawrenceRagan ok, in this case probably the best is you delete your question staying without answer, it cannot be useful for other people like that.